# How to auto logon a debian user by systembus?

Tags: python, dbus

After debian 10 enter logon ui on the console, which is lightdm greeter ui.
In the context of ssh session of root account, I want to logon another desktop user from the console ui by python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import dbus

def switch_to_user(username):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    manager_obj = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.DisplayManager', '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0')
    manager = dbus.Interface(manager_obj, 'org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.Seat')

    # Call the SwitchToUser method with the specified username
    ret = manager.SwitchToUser(username, '')
    print "manager.SwitchToUser ret = {0}".format(ret)

# Usage: Specify the username you want to switch to
switch_to_user("desktopuser1")
```

When run this python script, the logon screen flashes to black then recovered without user logon.

Then I found message in `/var/log/syslog`

> May 28 16:01:49 mynuc lightdm[649]: Stopping PAM conversation, interaction requested but not supported

What should I do? I tried authenciate the user with PAM service 'login' before swithToUser, still nothing happens.